# Moving static variables and related classes into a loop

Tags: javascript, class, variables, loops

I have some code in a Javascript file that was fixed at 3 elements.

I am now pulling items from a database so I need to convert it into a loop to create the right amount of elements.

I can't seem to figure out how to write my dynamic variables properly.

This is what I originally had:

```
var block0=$('#block0').offset().top;
var block1=$('#block1').offset().top;
var block2=$('#block2').offset().top;


$(window).scroll(function(){
windowScroll=$(window).scrollTop();

// conditional first item
if(windowScroll > block0){
    $('.arrow').show();
    $('.static_ele').hide(); 
    $('#block_1').show(); 
    $('#block_1').css({'position':'fixed','padding-top':0}); 
    $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
}else{
    $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block1'); 
}

// all central items
if(windowScroll > block1-200){
    $('.static_ele').hide(); 
    $('#block_2').show(); 
    $('#block_2').css('position','fixed');   
    $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block2'); 
    $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
}

// conditional last item
if(windowScroll > block2-200){
    $('.static_ele').hide();  
    $('#block_3').show(); 
    $('#block_3').css('position','fixed');  
    $('.arrow a').attr('href','#arrow1'); 
    $('.arrow a').addClass('upward');
}

})
```

This is where I have now got to:

```
var i=1;
var len={{collection.products_count}};

$(window).scroll(function(){
windowScroll=$(window).scrollTop();

    // first block
    if(windowScroll > $('#block0').offset().top){ 
        $('.arrow').show();
        $('.static_ele').hide(); 
        $('#block_1').show(); 
        $('#block_1').css({'position':'fixed','padding-top':0}); 
        $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
    }else{
        $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block1'); 
    }

    // central blocks
    for (i; i<len-2; i++)
    {
        if(windowScroll > $('#block'+i).offset().top-200){
            $('.static_ele').hide(); 
            $('#block_'+(i+1)).show();  
            $('#block_'+(i+1)).css('position','fixed');   
            $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block'+(i+1)); 
            $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
        }
    } // end for loop

    // last block
    if(windowScroll > $('#block'+(len-1)).offset().top-200){ 
        $('.static_ele').hide();  
        $('#block_'+len).show(); 
        $('#block_'+len).css('position','fixed');  
        $('.arrow a').attr('href','#arrow1'); 
        $('.arrow a').addClass('upward');
    }


}) // end window scroll function
```

Which still is not working.
If I take the items out of the four loop and manually enter them it works.
So if I replace the For loop above with

```
// central blocks
    if(windowScroll > $('#block1').offset().top-200){
        $('.static_ele').hide(); 
        $('#block_2').show();  
        $('#block_2').css('position','fixed');   
        $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block2'); 
        $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
    }

    if(windowScroll > $('#block2').offset().top-200){
        $('.static_ele').hide(); 
        $('#block_3').show();  
        $('#block_3').css('position','fixed');   
        $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block3'); 
        $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
    }
```

It then works perfectly for a scenario with 4 items.
So I think it is because all cases need to be accessible from within the windowScroll function which they aren't when contained within a for loop?? Is there another way to code this?

(A bit of background - this script is to hide and show divs as a user scrolls down a page. An arrow at the bottom of the page is available to click to next slide. When you reach the bottom the arrow turns up and takes you back to the top.)

Comment: Post your html, you should give an `id` to the container which wrap the elements, and replace `block0` to `$('#'+containerid).offset().top`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just try my best to fix syntax errors, and I haven't got what you really wanna do.

```
var i=0,
    j=0,
    len={{collection.products_count}};// Why use {{collection.products_count}}, Is there some server side script?

$(window).scroll(function(){
windowScroll=$(window).scrollTop();

    for (i; i<len; i++)
    {

        // first block
        if(i == 0){
            if(windowScroll > block0){
                $('.arrow').show();
                $('.static_ele').hide(); 
                $('#block_1').show(); 
                $('#block_1').css({'position':'fixed','padding-top':0}); 
                $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
            }else{
                $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block1'); 
            }
        } else {

        // last block
        if(i == len-1){
            if(windowScroll > $('#block_'+(i-1)).offset().top-200){
                $('.static_ele').hide();  
                $('#block_'+i).show(); 
                $('#block_'+i).css('position','fixed');  
                $('.arrow a').attr('href','#arrow1'); 
                $('.arrow a').addClass('upward');
            }
        } else {

        // all other blocks

            if(windowScroll > $('#block_'+i).offset().top-200){
                $('.static_ele').hide(); 
                $('#block_'+(i+1)).show(); 
                $('#block_'+(i+1)).css('position','fixed');   
                $('.arrow a').attr('href','#block_'+(i+1)); 
                $('.arrow a').removeClass('upward');
            }

        } // end testing which blocks

    } // end for loop

}) // end window scroll function
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help on this. It's really the correct syntax I was after, so your comments have helped me enormously.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code.

First of all you use the `[i]` instead of `i` for string catenation `"block" + [i]`, when all you should write is `"block" + i`. `[i]` creates a new array of size 1; this array is soon coerced into a string, which happily is the same as i.toString() in this case; that value is then concatenated to a string.

Secondly: instead of using IDs, you want to set a common class for all the blocks so that you can select them efficiently. Then you want to use JQuery each to loop through them instead of for.

Thirdly - your code "setting block variables" does 1 thing only

```
for (j; j<len; j++)
{   
    // set block vars
    var tem=block[j];
    tem=$('#block'+[j]).offset().top;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
j = len;
var tem = $('#block' + (len - 1)).offset().top;
```

That is all the side effects it has - it does not set any "block variables".

Instead of `else { if() { } }` write `else if () { }`.

Move all "loop invariants" out of the for loop altogether (that is `$('.static_ele').hide();` for example is run `len` times instead of only 1.

Lastly do not use for loop with *only* if loop variable contained within it - move the first if and last if out of the loop, and modify the for loop to run from second to second-last, to avoid the dreaded "for-case" paradigm.

After you write your code according to these guidances then it becomes more apparent what it is trying to do and actually answering your questions would become possible

Comment: Thanks so much for your time on this. I'm a newbie so these tips are really just what I needed.

Comment: I've updated the original question above with my new code (plus some extra notes). Works well if there are 3 items, but not for four. However, if I manually write the four items it works fine. I think the windowScroll function needs to access all options at once. Is there another way of stating the if statements outside of a for loop?